# How to set default value in sql so that is displays in db

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Table A
id b_id type size

Table B
id name
```

What important in A table is there are three values of type column: New, Activated, Archive.

And I set default value 0 to size column of A table and after insert command

```sql
insert into A (id, b_id, type, size) values (1, 101, 'New', 10)
```

I expected following result in A table:

#### Query

```sql
select * from A;
```

#### Table A result

| id | b_id | type | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | New | 10 |
| 2 | 101 | Activated | 0 |
| 3 | 101 | Archive | 0 |

But, it does not work. So how to reach that ?

Comment: Unless you add data to a table, there will not be anything in it.  You've inserted one row into the table, but the Activated and Archive rows have not been inserted yet.  You would have to run the insert commands for those two rows also.  Keep trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting just one row, so this will not automatically create three rows.

If you want three rows, including two with a default `size` value:

```
insert into A (id, b_id, type, size) values (1, 101, 'New', 10);
insert into A (id, b_id, type) values (1, 101, 'Activated');
insert into A (id, b_id, type) values (1, 101, 'Archive');
```

If you wanted to automatically duplicate the inserted row for the two other statuses, you could consider something like:

```
insert into A (id, b_id, type, size) 
values d.id, d.b_id, t.type, case when d.type = t.type then d.size else default end
from  (values (1, 101, 'New', 10)) d(id, b_id, type, size)
cross join (values ('New'), ('Activated'), ('Archive')) t(type)
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But there is a way to reach that in a database level automatically, without that additional, boiler code

Comment: @Nursultan: no, the database does not automatically creates rows under the hood, you have to be explicit about what you want in the query.

Comment: Not sure I understand well your objective ... If you want to systematically associate 3 fields size_new + activated_new + archive_new to the same row whose primary key is (id, b_id), then you should create 3 columns in your table 'size_new', 'activated_new', 'archive_new' with `DEFAULT 0` for the 2 last columns so that they are initialized with 0 by default.